# Call many cells from another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a very complicated formula:

```
=if(
and(A$1>$W4, A$1<=$X4, $X4>B$1),
$U4, 
if(and($W4>=A$1,$W4<B$1),
days(B$1,$W4)*($U4/days(B$1,A$1))+0, 
if(and($X4>A$1,$X4<=B$1),
days($X4,A$1)*($U4/days(B$1,A$1)),
0)))
```

And rather than type 'Other Sheet'!cell for every cell reference, I would like to know if there's a way I can describe the entire sheet prior to referencing cells from that sheet. I thought that perhaps this would work but it obviously doesn't. Any solutions?

```
=query('othersheet'!cell:cell,if(
and(A$1>$W4, A$1<=$X4, $X4>B$1),
$U4, 
if(and($W4>=A$1,$W4<B$1),
days(B$1,$W4)*($U4/days(B$1,A$1))+0, 
if(and($X4>A$1,$X4<=B$1),
days($X4,A$1)*($U4/days(B$1,A$1)),
0))))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately no, you still need to reference it

```
=IF(AND('othersheet'!A$1 >  'othersheet'!$W4, 
        'othersheet'!A$1 <= 'othersheet'!$X4, 
        'othersheet'!$X4 >  'othersheet'!B$1), 'othersheet'!$U4, 
 IF(AND('othersheet'!$W4 >= 'othersheet'!A$1,
        'othersheet'!$W4 <  'othersheet'!B$1),
 DAYS('othersheet'!B$1, 'othersheet'!$W4)*('othersheet'!$U4/
 DAYS('othersheet'!B$1, 'othersheet'!A$1))+0, 
 IF(AND('othersheet'!$X4 >  'othersheet'!A$1,
        'othersheet'!$X4 <= 'othersheet'!B$1),
 DAYS('othersheet'!$X4, 'othersheet'!A$1)*('othersheet'!$U4/
 DAYS('othersheet'!B$1, 'othersheet'!A$1)), 0)))
```

---

or you can put your formula into some auxiliary column in your `othersheet` (let's say X4) and then just reference

```
='othersheet'!X4
```